# No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:8080 in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I have my apps running on java spring.
After i start the tomcat in eclipse, it runs well
But after certain minutes +- 30 minutes. It shows "This localhost page can’t be found
No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:8080/testadmin/Dashboard"

if i try http://localhost:8080/testadmin **(it calls index.jsp)**, it shows the web. But function inside of index.jsp that call another controller function show 404 in the network console.

If i restart eclipse tomcat. The web runs well again. Is there any missing things on it ?

Answer (score 0):

That type of problem I mostly found in eclipse so you can only clean the eclipse cache then it's gonna work fine but now I switched to IntelliJ now it's fine.